# Get the top level category of a checkin/venue

Tags: java, switch-statement, foursquare

Is there a way to retrieve the top level category e.g Arts & Entertainment when i get all Checkins from a user?

my only idea is to do this manually with a huge switch-case including every subcategory.
somebody got a hint or a better idea to do this?

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the venues/categories endpoint to get a tree of all the categories. Then, use this to build a mapping from all categories to their corresponding top level category

Comment: I did it, the mapping was painful but it works. Thanks for the input